# HDIV - AJAX configuration

Tags: csrf, struts-1, csrf-protection, hdiv

This is the continuation of this question
 [HDIV - Multipart not configured - Struts 1.3 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673112/hdiv-multipart-not-configured-struts-1-3)

I made many changes in my pages to make it work for HDIV. But I could not fix the ajax calls. How to configure the HDIV for ajax requests? The ajax calls in my application usually fetches set of values that updates the dropdown select, or a json string that updates various page components.

Answer (score 0):

You have a shot explanation in that page: https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/wiki/Appendix-C:-Ajax

Briefly explained, you have to create all link and form elements server side, if they are created in client side HDIV doesn't have any way to process them.